# Edit link properties of social links (Wordpress)

Tags: css

Basically I want to edit/re-direct the links for my social icons (they're fonts) on a certain page. The same icons are used on my main page but I want them to lead to a different Facebook- and Youtube location than what's set on on my start page page. The link properties are set globally within the Wordpress CMS and they are inherited throughout the site. No option to set different for every page. They're tied a specific template...

Can I add a style in the style.css or something to make them lead elsewhere for a specific page and how would it look like? Thanks!!!

Here's the HTML and page id:

**The page id: body.page-id-85**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="thb-social-home">
    <a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
       <span class="thb-social-icon">2</span>
    </a>
    <a title="YouTube" href="http://www.youtube.com/">
       <span class="thb-social-icon">5</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

*I´ll add the suffixes later. The rest is correct for the page I want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to touch the CSS to change the link property, you can do it in HTML with the href property.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="thb-social-home">
    <a title="Facebook" href="CHANGE THIS">
       <span class="thb-social-icon">2</span>
    </a>
    <a title="YouTube" href="CHANGE THIS">
       <span class="thb-social-icon">5</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is the generated HTML viewed via Firebug. If I change this in the PHP it will change the links for main page aswell. I don't wan't to do that.

Comment: You can add a javascript to that specific page e.g: $("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")